# error en Git clone

Tags: git, github

amigos estoy tratando de aplicar un git clone a este repositorio:

https://github.com/safak/youtube/tree/chat-app

aplico esto desde cmd
_> git clone https://github.com/safak/youtube.git

tarda un buen rato, pero cuando termina me esta descargando otras carpetas, son las siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y segun el directorio de github debe clonar esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que esta pasando???

Comment: En qué rama estás parado en el local? Coloca la salida de este comando en la pregunta: `git branch`... también `git status`.

Comment: Ok... acabo de notar un detalle. El url que estás usando en el clone creo que no es el adeucado: `git clone  https://github.com/safak/youtube`

Comment: este fue el que use https://github.com/safak/youtube.git

Comment: al aplicar git branch me muestra: * smooth-menu     y al aplicar git status: On branch smooth-menu
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/smooth-menu'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Ok. Si, entonces si necesitamos la salida de `git branch` y `git status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el browser estás mostrando el contenido de la rama `chat-app` pero en tu local estás en la rama `smooth-menu` que tiene justo esos directorios que muestras en el local: https://github.com/safak/youtube/tree/smooth-menu. Si lo que quieres es trabajar sobre la rama `chat-app`:

```
git checkout chat-app
```

Comment: mi intencion era clonar el proyecto completo, es decir las carpetas api, client y socket..... acaso estan bloqueadas??

Comment: No. Al clonar de la forma en la que lo hiciste, git baja todo (todas la ramas y etiquetas). Lo que pasa es que estás en una rama diferente a la que esperas es en tu local (no sabría por qué). Pero puedes cambiar a la rama que quieres solo corriendo ese comando que puse en la respuesta.

Comment: gracias bro! voy aplicar el comando git checkout chat-app..... esto lo hago desde afuera de la carpeta "youtube" que fue la que se bajo

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta youtube.

Comment: listo bro!!! si funcino! gracias por tu ayuda